# c# allow only signed assemblies to be loaded

Tags: c#, security, sign

I have .NET 4.8 application. I want to setup application environment in a way that only assemblies (dlls) signed with trusted certificate could be loaded into application.

How can I achieve that? I guess I need to setup (or create new) AppDomain with certain settings, but after some searching I'm not sure how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Loaded at runtime?

Comment: Basically, I want all assemblies (referenced) and loaded at runtime to be checked.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why are the checks built into .NET not enough?

Comment: @Christopher Let me simplify it. In current version of app, .exe and dlls are digitally signed with trusted certificate. When I install this app, I can tamper dll (also signed) loaded during runtime with hex editor. By tampering it, I have broke consistency and I can see certificate is not trusted anymore (in properties of file). So far so good. The issue is that such a assembly is loaded during runtime. What shall I do to make runtime throw exception or something?

Comment: Sorry Guys :( What I was trying to say is that I tamper with assembly file (dll). That should makes it basically 'not trusted' anymore.

Comment: But you are missing the point. If your security is compromised to the point where a dll in a trusted location has been tampered, then nothing is stoping the attacker from tampering your .exe to circumvent any protection you might implement to protect yourself. Its a lost war...

Comment: If I have access to your app with a hex-editor, I would disable the check for signed assemblies.

Comment: [Simplest way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/disable-strong-name-bypass-feature)

Comment: @HansPassant But does that help in any way? Any attacker that has compromised the system to the point where he has access to a fully trusted location and can tamper dlls, will probably be able to tamper any specific application configuration file or general registry setting and enable the bypass again, won't he? Its simply about knowing what to look for. I'm guessing it would help in the case of assemblies loaded up in runtime that were maybe downloaded by the user.

Answer (score 3):

> When I install this app, I can tamper dll (also signed) loaded during runtime with hex editor.

If the enemy has that kind of access to your memory, there is nothing you can do. Everything you **could** do, could be **undone** with a similar attack on your main programm.

Whatever check you would put into the code, you can not trust it because it could be attacked the very same way.

Comment: Agreed. One scenario when this would actually make sense is when a dll is loaded from an untrusted source (or through an untrusted channel), but I'd say that's a rather special case.